# Uart communication with MPlabX Ide

Tags: c, string, serial-port, pic, uart

I am using Mplab x Ide with v3.61  on Xc8 compiler, PIC18F24K40. I used MCC generated UART code for send and receive data. For understanding I am clubling my code and posting part of it.

My main code look like this.

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#define EUSART_TX_BUFFER_SIZE 8
#define EUSART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 8

/**
  Section: Global Variables
*/

volatile uint8_t eusartTxHead = 0;
volatile uint8_t eusartTxTail = 0;
volatile uint8_t eusartTxBuffer[EUSART_TX_BUFFER_SIZE];
volatile uint8_t eusartTxBufferRemaining;

volatile uint8_t eusartRxHead = 0;
volatile uint8_t eusartRxTail = 0;
volatile uint8_t eusartRxBuffer[EUSART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE];
volatile uint8_t eusartRxCount;


#define LED_RX RC7 // Pin assigned RX LED
#define LED_TX RC6 // Pin assigned TX LED
#define LED RC2 // Pin assigned for LED 
#define DE RC5


unsigned int count=0;
char data=0;
static int DEVICE_ID=1;
char rxbuf[50]=" ";
unsigned char Function_code=0X03;
static int index=0;
static int rec_flag = 0;
static int check_flag = 1;

unsigned char buff[10];

char data1[10];
unsigned char buf[20]; //array to hold twenty bytes





void EUSART_Initialize(void)
{
    // disable interrupts before changing states
    PIE3bits.RCIE = 0;
    PIE3bits.TXIE = 0;

    // Set the EUSART module to the options selected in the user interface.

    // ABDOVF no_overflow; SCKP Non-Inverted; BRG16 16bit_generator; WUE disabled; ABDEN disabled; 
    BAUD1CON = 0x08;

    // SPEN enabled; RX9 8-bit; CREN enabled; ADDEN disabled; SREN enabled; 
    RC1STA = 0xB0;

    // TX9 8-bit; TX9D 0; SENDB sync_break_complete; TXEN enabled; SYNC asynchronous; BRGH hi_speed; CSRC master; 
    TX1STA = 0xA4;

    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1; //As Prescribed in Datasheet
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 1; 
    RC1STAbits.CREN=1;
    TX1STAbits.TXEN=1;

    // Baud Rate = 9600; SP1BRGL 207; 
    SP1BRGL = 0xCF;

    // Baud Rate = 9600; SP1BRGH 0; 
    SP1BRGH = 0x00;


    // initializing the driver state
    eusartTxHead = 0;
    eusartTxTail = 0;
    eusartTxBufferRemaining = sizeof(eusartTxBuffer);

    eusartRxHead = 0;
    eusartRxTail = 0;
    eusartRxCount = 0;

    // enable receive interrupt
    PIE3bits.RCIE = 1;
}







uint8_t EUSART_Read(void)
{
    uint8_t readValue = 0;

    while(0 == eusartRxCount)
    {
    }

    readValue = eusartRxBuffer[eusartRxTail++];
    if(sizeof(eusartRxBuffer) <= eusartRxTail)
    {
        eusartRxTail = 0;
    }
    PIE3bits.RCIE = 0;
    eusartRxCount--;
    PIE3bits.RCIE = 1;
    eusartRxBuffer[8];

    return readValue;
}

void EUSART_Write(uint8_t txData)
{
    while(0 == eusartTxBufferRemaining)
    {
    }

    if(0 == PIE3bits.TXIE)
    {
        TX1REG = txData;
    }
    else
    {
        PIE3bits.TXIE = 0;
        eusartTxBuffer[eusartTxHead++] = txData;
        if(sizeof(eusartTxBuffer) <= eusartTxHead)
        {
            eusartTxHead = 0;
        }
        eusartTxBufferRemaining--;
    }
    PIE3bits.TXIE = 1;
}

char getch(void)
{
    return EUSART_Read();
}

void putch(char txData)
{
    EUSART_Write(txData);
}

void EUSART_Transmit_ISR(void)
{

    // add your EUSART interrupt custom code
    if(sizeof(eusartTxBuffer) > eusartTxBufferRemaining)
    {
        TX1REG = eusartTxBuffer[eusartTxTail++];
        if(sizeof(eusartTxBuffer) <= eusartTxTail)
        {
            eusartTxTail = 0;
        }
        eusartTxBufferRemaining++;
    }
    else
    {
        PIE3bits.TXIE = 0;
    }
}

void EUSART_Receive_ISR(void)
{

    if(1 == RC1STAbits.OERR)
    {
        // EUSART error - restart

        RC1STAbits.CREN = 0;
        RC1STAbits.CREN = 1;
    }

    // buffer overruns are ignored
    eusartRxBuffer[eusartRxHead++] = RC1REG;
    if(sizeof(eusartRxBuffer) <= eusartRxHead)
    {
        eusartRxHead = 0;
    }
    eusartRxCount++;
}










/* Send Data Serially */
 void send_string(const char *x)
 {
     while(*x)
     {
        EUSART_Write(*x++); 
     }
 }






/* Timer Interrupt Service Routine Program*/
void Blink_Count()
{
   if(PIR0bits.TMR0IF == 1)
   { 
       PIR0bits.TMR0IF =0;
       count=count+1;
       if(count>=15)
       {
          // LED=!LED;
           count=0;

       }

   }

}

void main(void)
{

    while (1)
    {
   data= EUSART_Read();
     rxbuf[10]=data;
     printf("%s\n",&rxbuf[10]);
     __delay_ms(150);

    }

}
```

And tested Serial communication. with this code i could print welcome on Serial Monitor

```
void main(void)
{
  EUSART_Initialize();
    while (1)
    {
     char array[20] = "Hello World";
     printf("%s\n",array);
      __delay_ms(150);

    }

}
```

The problem i am facing is. When i try to send data 0103000000Ac5CD In ASCii format i receice as charcter ,but when i try to send in hex format i could not able to receive nothing. If am printing data like i used in working hello print example i got garbage value.

[Hex Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EHb7.jpg)

[ascii data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTzYe.jpg)

[hELLO WORLD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8eHP.jpg)

Comment: Looks like the code is sending a line feed for end of line (0) and after every non-printing character

Comment: What does the send routine look like?  It is possible that that is the output of the send routine.

Comment: I do this by creating a binary file using sublime and use cat file.bin > /dev/ttyUSB0 to send the data. This is easy to use and reuse. Maybe this can help you? You can be sure that this solution will send the data. You can always try to loop back the data to see what's going on.